# Get elastic search query from spring data Jpa

Tags: elasticsearch, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

In my code base, I have two code for search on elastic.

1. One is through ElasticSearchTemplte from there I build the elastic query and query on elastic.
2. In the second one, I am querying through spring-data-jpa.

In the first case, I can see my elastic search query and can directly query on ES.

My question is
**Is there any way to get that elastic query from spring-data-jpa.**

I want to see what spring-data-jpa is building the query before it hit ES.

Answer (score 0):

Spring-boot with Query-Dsl provides the elastic search. Follow [this](https://github.com/querydsl/querydsl/tree/master/querydsl-jpa). and this [tutorial](https://www.petrikainulainen.net/programming/spring-framework/spring-data-jpa-tutorial-part-five-querydsl/)  Below the dependency and plugin

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
  <artifactId>querydsl-jpa</artifactId>
  <version>${querydsl.version}</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
  <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
  <version>1.6.1</version>
</dependency>


<project>
  <build>
    <plugins>
      ...
      <plugin>
        <groupId>com.mysema.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>apt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.3</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>process</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <outputDirectory>target/generated-sources/java</outputDirectory>
              <processor>com.querydsl.apt.jpa.JPAAnnotationProcessor</processor>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
        <dependencies>
          <dependency>
            <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
            <artifactId>querydsl-apt</artifactId>
            <version>${querydsl.version}</version>
          </dependency>
        </dependencies>
      </plugin>
      ...
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```